# Hyper-V and HAXM

Tags: android, hyper-v, haxm

I am brand new to the Android development scene, but I am eager to learn. I was working on installing Android Studio when I saw that HAXM could not install because VT-X was not enabled. Some quick googling saw that I had to first disable Hyper-V and then I would be able to install HAXM? I am wondering if it is OK to disable Hyper-V in order to install HAXM and whether I can or should re-enable it after installation of HAXM. Is this the right way to install this? Do I need Hyper-V enabled?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Only one virtualization can be active at a time. I would try disabling Hyper-V then try installing and using HAXM.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! So you are saying that because HAXM is a visualization that I should disable Hyper-V and install and use HAXM? Do I need Hyper-V? What does Windows utilize it for when I am just using my laptop for stuff other than Android development?

Comment: HAXM is a _virtualization_ :). You can disable Hyper-V from windows, no need to do anything from the BIOS, go to This PC or This Computer then check this: http://prntscr.com/7eg0z9

Comment: Ok, I see how to do that, however, do I need Hyper-V enabled for anything or am I good to go ahead and disable it for the foreseeable future?

Comment: Well basically if you don't know if you need it, you probably don't! :) The first thing that comes to mind that uses it is Windows Phone 8 emulator.

Comment: Aah I see! Thanks for your patience with me, as I am new to Android development, and have never really had the need for an emulator before!

Comment: We all start somewhere! Glad I could help :).

Comment: I went to actually do this today, and I don't have hyper-v listed in the windows features menu. What should I do?

Comment: Well you still have to enable VT-X in BIOS for it to work. You just can't use HAXM and Hyper-V together.

Answer (score 6):

Both, Hyper-V and HAXM are hypervisors used to run virtual machines. You must decide which must be enabled depending on what you want to run on your laptop.

- *You need Hyper-V* if you want to use the Android Emulators provided by Microsofr, run Virtual Machines on Hyper-V, use Windows Containers, use Docker for Windows, use Vagrant with Hyper-V or Docker, or use any other application that requires it.
- *You cannot enable Hyper-V* if you want to run VirtualBox or use Vagrant with VirtualBox
- *You need HAXM* if you want to accelerate the execution of the Android emulator (and you do not have Hyper-V and you do not use Virtualbox at the same time).

Answer (score 0):

Right, I figured I had to enable Intel virtualization from the BIOS. I've got the emulator working now! Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with a similar processor, core i3, in my VAIO laptop.  VT was also enabled on the BIOS and the problem was fixed when I uninstalled the avast anti-virus(no disabling the protection) and so I could finish the HAMX installation. After that, I installed the Avast software again.

I hope this issue can help more people.